# How to make ContentControl stretch horizontally

Tags: silverlight, layout

I've set the HorizontalAlignment property to stretch but it did not help.

**I need that content control since in my real code the DataGrid is injected with prism into the content control.**

XAML:

```
<ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid>
        <Controls:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"></Controls:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</ContentControl>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        Persons = new List<Person>();
        Persons.Add(new Person { Name = "A",Age = 5});
        Persons.Add(new Person { Name = "A", Age = 5 });
        Persons.Add(new Person { Name = "A", Age = 5 });

        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}


public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to `Stretch`